# If $(\mathbb{Z}_n\setminus\{0\}, \otimes)$ is a group, prove that $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ is prime.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. Define the congruence class $\overline x$ as

$$\overline x = \{c\in\mathbb{Z}\;|\; c-x\equiv0\pmod{n}\}$$

Define $\mathbb{Z}_n$, the set of all congruence classes modulo $n$:

$$\mathbb{Z}_n = \{\overline0, \overline1, \ldots, \overline{n-1}\}$$

Finally, define the operation $\otimes$ as

$$\overline{a} \otimes \overline{b} = \overline{a\times b}$$

where $a\times b$ represents regular multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Using Bezout's Theorem (Let $a,b\in\mathbb{z}$, then $\gcd(a, b) = 1 \iff \exists u, v\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $au+bv = 1$.) prove that if $(\mathbb{Z}_n\setminus\{0\}, \otimes)$ is a group then $n$ is prime.

---

My Attempt:

Take an $\overline x\in\mathbb{Z}_n\setminus\{0\}$. The set $\overline x$ contains all $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ that satisfy the following congruence:

$$c-x \equiv0\pmod{n}$$

In other words,

$$x \equiv c\pmod{n}$$

Therefore, for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$,

$$c^{-1}\cdot x \equiv 1\pmod{n} \implies c^{-1}\cdot x = 1 + m\cdot n$$

Re-arranging this and using Bezout's theorem, we get

$$c^{-1}\cdot x - m\cdot n = 1 \implies \gcd(x, n) = 1$$

Since $\overline{x}$ was taken arbitrarily, we can say that $n$ is prime.

---

Comments:

I don't think this is correct because I haven't really used group axioms and I've assumed $c^{-1}$ exists.

Could you spot where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group axioms demand that $c^{-1}$ exists, so you have used one of them.  I think a simpler approach is to say that if $n$ is not prime, you can factor it into two numbers $a,b \in \Bbb Z_n$.  Then the multiplication operation is not defined for $a \otimes b$, so it is not a group.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Ross. Your proposed approach seems much simpler!